# Store persistent data in session

Tags: session, web-applications, store, persistent

This might be super stupid. Shoot me, but I was in a strange mood yesterday and thought about the following:

What if I store webapp data in a persistent way, just by using sessions. So I store a sessioncookie with an hash, way longer so it's not bruteable. Then just save all stored data in the session. I also set sessiontime to unlimited...

Would there be any use for this? :D

Comment: are those data not required to persist on server restart?

Comment: could be? It does not have to be removed on server restart, is it? I don't know, It was just a brainfart I don't see any use in it. I was just wondering. :P

Answer (score 2):

Not really. Most session state implementations keep the sessions in-memory. On app restart (or  hardware failure, etc) memory is cleared and session cache is lost.

You could do so if you have your sessions stored in a database rather than in-proc but could be a  bit of work depending on what platform you're working with. It's slower as well.

Generally you don't want to keep sessions very large because if they are in-proc sessions, you're going to eat up your servers memory real fast. Even if you go with the database approach for sessions, this is still often done but using in-memory temp tables for sessions and, therefore will eat up the ram of the database server.

Sessions should be light-weight and non-essential to the applications functionality. For anything important that must be persisted, keep it in a database.